# NAudio Convert Byte Array to Wav

Tags: c#, naudio

I looked into NAudio classes but couldn't see a class that converts byte array to WAV file. If there is no class like this, how can I convert byte array to WAV file using NAudio?

I want to send a text to RS232 as bytes, then I will get back those bytes into a `byte[]` buffer. After getting back data I want to save them as a WAV file using NAudio.

I tried to use `WaveBuffer` class but I think I am trying a wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This blog post](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-use-wavefilewriter.html) explains how to use the `WaveFileWriter` class for this purpose:

```
byte[] testSequence = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0xFF, 0xFE };
using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(fileName, waveFormat))
{
    writer.WriteData(testSequence, 0, testSequence.Length);
}
```